# WinError 2 - os.path.getmtime not locating file in Python 3

Tags: python, loops, os.path

I am having difficulty with a bit of code designed to write the "Last Modified" date of a number of files to a CSV document.

I have everything else functioning properly, however this function returns:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'filenamesoandso.docx'
```

Here is context:

```
pathList = ["S:\\BUILDING\\",
        "S:\\ONGOING PROJECTS\FACILITY OPERATIONS\OPERATIONS\\"
        ]

def file_date_modified(pathList):
sys.stdout = open("date modified.txt", "w+")
for root, dirs, files, in os.walk(a):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".pdf"):
             print(time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(file)))
        if file.endswith(".pptx"):
             print(time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(file)))
        if file.endswith(".doc"):
             print(time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(file)))
        if file.endswith(".docx"):
             print(time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(file)))
        if file.endswith(".xlsx"):
             print(time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(file)))

for a in pathList:
    file_date_modified()
```

I realize this error usually suggests it's looking in the wrong directory, but have been unable to come up with a fix based off of replies to other questions here. Here's an example of another function I have been using that works correctly and I'm not sure why this one identifies the correct path and the former does not.

```
def file_name_print(pathList):
sys.stdout = open("file names.txt", "w+")
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(a):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".pdf"):
             print(os.path.splitext(file)[0])
        if file.endswith(".pptx"):
             print(os.path.splitext(file)[0])
        if file.endswith(".doc"):
             print(os.path.splitext(file)[0])
        if file.endswith(".docx"):
             print(os.path.splitext(file)[0])
        if file.endswith(".xlsx"):
             print(os.path.splitext(file)[0])
```

I'm still a rookie so it's possible I am overlooking something stupid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to append the directory to the file name, as the directory of the file is different from the current working directory of the script, as it seems.

On way to do this could be:

```
for file in files:
    file_path = os.path.join(root, file)

    if file.endswith(".pdf"):
         print(time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(file_path)))
```

Does that work for you?

Comment: Accidentally hit "enter" on the reply before it was done.

Comment: Oops, accidentally hit "enter" on the reply before it was done. The error has changed to a WinError 3 and I can see that it may be due to the amount of backslashes/ escape characters that the program generates: 

{FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'S:\\ONGOING PROJECTS\\FACILITY OPERATIONS\\ONGOING\\}

Comment: Maybe remove all slashes and backslashes and use `os.path.join('S:', 'BUILDING')` instead

Comment: Yes, it looks like the problem is in the backslashes and the way the program is parsing those. But, your solution does appear to have fixed my problem. Thanks!